# Replicate code alignment function in php (align strings on equals sign)

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP function to replicate the code alignment technique common in many code editors where this:

```
    $age -> id = $payload["id"];
    $age -> range = $payload["range"];
```

Will be changed to this:

```
    $age -> id    = $payload["id"];
    $age -> range = $payload["range"];
```

What's the best way to go about this? For the purposes of my current needs, I'm aligning on the equals sign, but I suppose the code should be able to work with any given character (or sequence of characters).

As a starting point, here's some boilerplate:

```
function alignCode($text, $align_on = "=")
{
    return $text;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode each line by the first delimiter. Find out the length of the longest leading (ie. left of delimiter) part of a line. (Ponder if you want to align by the max-length found in the file, or align per the current code block?) Loop over the lines and right-pad *max-minus-current-length* amount of spaces to all leading strings. Implode lines back together. Delimiters will then become aligned.

Give it a try and write some relevant code into that boilerplate function of yours. If there are problems after trying to code it yourself, I will update this answer and help review your current effort.